# sh file not found in linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, steam

I'm an owner of synology's diskstation NAS server running on special OS (mainly linux)

It has only access from internet. I established command line interface to access it using synology wiki. Now I try to install Counter-Strike server on it using SteamCMD. I just look in Valve Developer Community for it.

I'm writing the next:

```
mkdir csServer  
cd csServer
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
tar xvfz steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
./steamcmd.sh
```

But the last line causes `-sh: ./steamcmd.sh not found`. However, I can see this file in the directory.

[image]

What actually can cause it?

**//ADDED**

The file is executable!

[image]

Comment: Is `steamcmd.sh` executable?  Please run `stat steamcmd.sh` from the command line and post the results.

Comment: Your code says "csServer", but your `stat` output says "DiskStation". Which is correct?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Actually i wrote `cd csServer` it changed the folder, but the name DiskStation doesn't changed. Actually I'm working with directory csServer. I'm in it.

Comment: What do `echo $SHELL` and `file /bin/bash` say?

Comment: @mguerri I updated the question, the second one may be the clu) changing file to steamcmd.sh still causing error

Comment: @mguerri how can i check if file is executable (`stat /bin/bash` not working)

Comment: Try `stat /bin/bash` and `stat /opt/bin/bash` and post the results

Comment: @mguerri No such file or directory, i can't use `ipkg install bash` although. It says `ipkg not found`, but actually I just found a thread for my nas server where says how to install ipkg function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65846/discussion-between-mguerri-and-olexiy-pyvovarov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script contains a header which says `#!/bin/bash`, that is *use /bin/bash to execute this script*. Apparently, on your system `/bin/bash` is not present. I am not familiar with Synology environment, but you should be able to fix this problem by installing bash and then pointing your script to the right path, which should be `/opt/bin/bash`. The first line of your script should therefore look like the following

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
```

You could also use Synology default `ash`, but beware that you script might not work as it was written for `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Windows style end-of-lines (CRLF) can cause this issue. If your sh file contains Windows style end-of-lines, convert it to Linux style.